# gradle execution failed for task :compileTestJava

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying to build my project but I get this error

```
Execution failed for task ':compileTestJava'
>Copilation failed; see the compiler error output for details
```

This is my build file:

```
apply plugin: "application"
apply plugin: "java"

mainClassName = "<package>.Main"

repositories
    {
    jcenter
        {
        url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
        }
    }

dependencies
    {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox
    implementation group: 'org.apache.pdfbox', name: 'pdfbox', version: '2.0.1'
    }

test
    {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging
        {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
        }
    }
```

I updated my build file. Now the project builds by using gradle run, but it doesn't using gradle check. Am I missing some dependencies to be able to use my test classes?

Comment: What version of Gradle do you use?

Comment: @LukasKörfer 4.4.1

Comment: unrelated, but PDFBox is at 2.0.19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Gradle 4.6 or later for JUnit 5 support.

Unless you have a specific reason for using such an old version, you will probably want to use the latest (which at this time is 6.4).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am working on a linux environment and it seems that the version 4.4.1 is the latest one that is being provided for linux systems. At least it is the version that gets installed by using apt-get install

Comment: Usually it is better to use the [Gradle Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) for invoking (and downloading) a declared version of Gradle for a given project. That way you don't have to rely on what your system provides, which may also not match what the project was created to work with.

Comment: So I downloaded and installed the latest version of gradle and now I am getting a different error with the same build file. The error says Task 'run' not found in root project '<projectName>'.

Comment: The "run" task probably comes from the [Application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html), which you need to apply.